# ORACLE : found a date out of range : -5000 BC ?! (inserted by hibernate)

Tags: oracle, hibernate, date, jdbc, limit

As you may know, Oracle's limits are -4713 to +9999 for full year in date fields.
I'm working on a 11g database and I've found sereval records with a year out of range (-5386, -5459, -5592 etc).

On SQL Developper I tried :

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI AD';
select the_date_field, to_char(the_date_field, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI AD') FROM the_table WHERE ...
```

It gives me the result:
    26/09/5386 05:23 AV.J.-C. | 00/00/0000 00:00 00000000
(fr display, "av" means "before")

I got an impossible date and "TO_CHAR" function can't work and returns "00/00/0000" (yeah, another impossible date!) ; but SQL Developper display this field well.

I also tried :
select the_date_field **+ 1** FROM the_table WHERE ...
And I obtain: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

So it really looks like a real Date.
"describe the_table" gives : "the_date_field                    DATE"

This data was inserted by a j2ee application using Hibernate v3.0.5, with oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver v12.1.0.2.0.
Hibernate property "the_date_field" is also set to "timestamp" (it shouldn't be a problem, indeed?).
Issue repeats over time but I still didn't figure out how to reproduce it.

The others billions of records in this old application have no problem.

Anyone has an idea of what's going on?

Comment: what is the result of: select to_char(my_weird_date, 'j') from my_table;

Comment: what is the result of `select dump(my_weird_date) from my_table;`?

Comment: @tbone : result of "to_char(my_weird_date, 'j') " is : **0000000**

Comment: @Matthew McPeak : result of dump(my_weird_date) is **Typ=12 Len=7: 45,8,9,2,15,16,1**

Comment: 22/03/5589 09:30 AV.J.-C.  =>    Typ=12 Len=7: 45,11,3,22,10,31,1   looks like it's -10100 + 45*100 + 11 = -5589 . Data is correct in some sort of way. My question is : how could it be inserted ? Why Oracle didn't throw an error on insertion?

Comment: I just tried to manually insert extreme dates with the application (the only one that write in this database): -4712 is ok ; Oracle's driver throws an error for -4713 and before. Looks like normal. The -5000Y records looks even weirder now...

Comment: did you have any solution for your problem?